ローカルのNexusインスタンスをAzure Container Registryに接続できない
私はプロジェクトのために、Azure Container Registry (ACR)に接続するように設定されたDockerプロキシで、3つの別々のローカルNexusインスタンス(各データセンターに1つ)をセットアップしようとしています。目標は、各データセンターのNexusリポジトリをACRに保存されたイメージのローカルキャッシュとして機能させ、デプロイ毎にリモートレジストリからプルする必要性を減らすことです。私は以下のステップを踏んだ：
Docker Composeファイル（2つのインスタンス用）と手動インストール（1つのインスタンス用）を使用して、3つの異なるデータセンター用にNexusインスタンスをセットアップした。各NexusインスタンスにDockerプロキシリポジトリを設定し、Azure Container Registryに接続。同じリポジトリを作成するなど、3つのNexusインスタンスすべてに同じ設定をレプリケートしました。
しかし、セットアップ完了後、3つのNexusインスタンスはすべて「Ready to Connect」状態のままで、リポジトリはACRに接続されておらず「Remote Available」と表示されています。認証情報と設定を再確認しましたが、問題を特定できないようです。Azureコンテナレジストリに接続するためにNexusインスタンスをセットアップするときに、同じような問題に遭遇した人はいますか？トラブルシューティングの手順や可能性のある解決策について、何かご提案があれば、ぜひ教えてください。
詳細
Azure Container Registry： Azure ACR
Nexusのバージョン Nexus 3
使用したDocker Composeファイル
version: '3'
services:
  nexus:
    image: docker.io/sonatype/nexus3
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 8g
    volumes:
      - /opt/nexus-data:/nexus-data
    ports:
      - "8081-8085:8081-8085"

よろしくお願いします！
current nexus setup
expected outcome
current nexus realms
current nexus repo config 1
current nexus repo config 2
current nexus repo config 3
